# BeautifulSoup returning [] when I run it

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful soup with python to retrieve weather data from a website.

Here's how the website looks like:

```xml
<channel>
<title>2 Hour Forecast</title>
<source>Meteorological Services Singapore</source>
<description>2 Hour Forecast</description>
<item>
<title>Nowcast Table</title>
<category>Singapore Weather Conditions</category>
<forecastIssue date="18-07-2016" time="03:30 PM"/>
<validTime>3.30 pm to 5.30 pm</validTime>
<weatherForecast>
<area forecast="TL" lat="1.37500000" lon="103.83900000" name="Ang Mo Kio"/>
<area forecast="SH" lat="1.32100000" lon="103.92400000" name="Bedok"/>
<area forecast="TL" lat="1.35077200" lon="103.83900000" name="Bishan"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.30400000" lon="103.70100000" name="Boon Lay"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.35300000" lon="103.75400000" name="Bukit Batok"/>
<area forecast="CL" lat="1.27700000" lon="103.81900000" name="Bukit Merah"/>` 
<channel>
```

I would like to retrieve 3.30 pm to 5.30 pm which is between **validTime**

After inspecting elements from the page, I found that 3.30 pm to 5.30 pm is in the "class = Text" within the `<span>` element:

[image: Inspect element of the website]

Based on the webiste, here are my python codes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.nea.gov.sg/api/WebAPI/?dataset=2hr_nowcast&keyref=<keyrefnumber>"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

g_data = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "text"})

print g_data

# to print out the file in 3.30pm to 5:30pm to an XML file
outfile = open('C:\scripts\idk.xml','w')
```

When I run my python codes in CMD, all I got was `[]`.

Comment: Are you sure your `find_all` with class `text` is correct? As you stated above the "class = Text" <-- with capital **T**

Comment: @Anzel: the screenshot show a lowercase `t`. But the XML the OP posted with the `validText` tag doesn't at all match what the screenshot shows, so I suspect this is *dynamic content*, not present in the actual raw HTML loaded from the URL.

Comment: You are accessing the API directly, so you are getting your XML response. It doesn't matter what some HTML page with javascript code does with this API, the API serves you *XML data*. Parse that data as XML and get yourself the `validTime` element, not some `<span>`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, as always I think you're right. I didn't even look at the image as the **T** was in my mind when I see discrepancies

Comment: @MartijnPieters, how do you suggest I parse the data as XML and get the validTime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [main API page on the Singapore NEA site](https://www.nea.gov.sg/api/) shows clearly that the response you get is an XML document:

> 2-hour Nowcast
>   **Data Description**: Weather forecast for next 2 hours
>   **Last API Update**:  1-Mar-2016
>   **Frequency** Hourly
>   **File Type**:    XML

You are looking at a HTML representation of the data in Chrome; Chrome transformed the XML to make it presentable in some way, but your Python code is still accessing the XML directly. The [PDF documentation](https://www.nea.gov.sg/docs/default-source/api/developer's-guide.pdf?sfvrsn=2) and your own question show the actual XML contents, parse *those*.

If you want to use BeautifulSoup with XML, make sure you have the [`lxml` project](http://lxml.de/) installed and use the `'xml'` parser type. Then simply access the text content of the `validTime` element:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "xml")
valid_time = soup.find('validTime').string
```

Demo:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.nea.gov.sg/api/WebAPI/?dataset=2hr_nowcast&keyref=<private_api_key>')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "xml")
>>> soup.find('validTime').string
u'4.00 pm to 6.00 pm'
```

If you are trying to write to an XML file, you'd have to make sure it is writing *valid XML* however; this is outside the scope of BeautifulSoup.

Alternatively, use the [`ElementTree` API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) that comes with Python by default; it can both parse the XML and produce new XML.